# What is the best way to pass global config variables to handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Ive a nodejs app with express-handlebars and i am wanting to define variable for things like the 'host' address for CSS and Javascript that are currently being imported in a header.hbs file that i call form within the specific layout.

Ive created a config.js file which has a number of variables i want to set and ive imported that into the app.js  using:

```
var config = require('./config.js');
```

but then im lost as t where to go. for example i was thinkging if i can some how do something like this:

```
 <link href="{{config.csshost}}basev1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Can anyone provide some pointers, am stumped other than declaring these variable every time i load the template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would set the app locals:

```
var app = express()

app.locals = {
     config: config,
     templateVar: 'test'
 }
```

Edit:

Your routes will look something like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {config: config});
})
```

What this does, is then update the **app.locals** variable in express to look like this:

```
app.locals = {
   config: config
}
```

All the **app.local** variables are then accessible in your templates via:

```
{{config}}

//which is really
app.locals['config']
```

So, in your app.js where you configure express you would do this:

```
var app = express();

app.locals.config = require('./config')

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  return res.render('index')
})
```

Comment: thanks, but im not sure how to interpret the above?  could you explain what this is doing and how i would inject those vars into a layout?

Comment: This is all you have to do. When rendering a template and passing it variables, all this does is update the app.locals which then pass these to your template scope.

Comment: This works great. However was a little bit confusing for me. So just using `app.locals.config = require('./config')` made it possible to access the config object (via `{{ config.property }}`) in my handlebar template. So just look at the last code block ;)

Answer (score 2):

(This should be a comment to [sctskw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28620038/1560738) above, but I don't have enough reputation to do that.)

Rather than overwriting `app.locals` with a new object, it would be better to add new properties to the existing one, like this:

```
app.locals.config = config;
app.locals.templateVar = 'test';
```

The reason is that Express uses `app.locals` internally. Overwriting it would lose some useful variables Express provides. For example, we could use `settings.env` to detect the current running environment in a view template, which is defined as `app.locals.settings.env` by Express.